# PHP Creating a MySQL table am I using the wrong version?

Tags: php, mysql

So I am trying to teach myself PHP by using tutorials. I followed a tutorial but I keep getting an error when trying to create a MySQL table in my database. Here is the code:

```
$sql = 'CREATE TABLE servers (PID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY(PID), firstName CHAR(30), lastName CHAR(30), 
                mon CHAR(5), tues CHAR(5), wed CHAR(5) thur CHAR(5), fri CHAR(5), sat CHAR(5) sun CHAR(5),maxShifts INT, minShifts INT)';
```

This is the error I am receiving: Failed Table CreationYou have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'thur CHAR(5), fri CHAR(5), sat CHAR(5) sun CHAR(5),maxShifts INT, minShifts INT)' at line 2

I am using MySQL 5.5 and when I was trying to look up syntax to see what I might be doing wrong it seemed to be completely different from what I'm doing. I just want to know if I am on the right track, or if I should start looking for a new tutorial.

Comment: you need a comma after `wed CHAR(5)`. Change `wed CHAR(5) thur CHAR(5),` to `wed CHAR(5), thur CHAR(5),` AND thanks to @kimbarcelona after `sat CHAR(5)` -> change `sat CHAR(5) sun CHAR(5),` to `sat CHAR(5), sun CHAR(5),`

Comment: @Sean - also after sat CHAR(5). Change sat CHAR(5) sun CHAR(5), to sat CHAR(5), sun CHAR(5),

Comment: Wow I can't believe it was that simple. Ugh I feel like an idiot for even having to post that. Thank you two so much!

Comment: Ok :) please tick the check of my answer later on. Pay more attention next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've missed the comma.

```
$sql = 'CREATE TABLE servers (PID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY(PID), firstName CHAR(30), lastName CHAR(30), 
                mon CHAR(5), tues CHAR(5), wed CHAR(5), thur CHAR(5), fri CHAR(5), sat CHAR(5), sun CHAR(5),maxShifts INT, minShifts INT)';
```